# Does the ferry terminal for Okinawa in Kagoshima have free Wi-Fi? Does it have access to power outlets?

Tags: japan, ferries, wifi, kyushu

The ferry from Kagoshima at the south of mainland Japan to Okinawa leaves at around 5.30pm to 6.00pm which is a good number of hours after the checkout time of most accommodation.

I know from experience that many ferry terminals in Japan have free Wi-Fi and seem to recall some having power outlets available though all over Japan it's common to see power outlets that need a special plug, have covers over them, or have little signs saying they're not for public use.

The name of the terminal is Amami Okinawa Ferry Terminal (奄美・沖縄フェリーターミナル) and the only websites I can find are for the two ferry companies that operate there, not for the terminal itself: [A Line](https://www.aline-ferry.com/), [Marix Line](http://www.marixline.com/). Both websites have little or no English. The A Line site tells me there is Internet on the ferry itself but I can't find anything about the Marix ferry or the terminal building on either site.

Does anybody know from experience of from superior web search skills?

Comment: Free wifi is surprisingly rare in Japan, my vague understanding is that this is due to laws that basically make the wifi owner liable for whatever happens on their network unless they register their users.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Actually I found it much much easier to find free WiFi on my recent 2.5 month visit to Japan than on my previous visits over the years including just 6 months before the pandemic. There seem to be many now that use the same or very similar couple of captive portals. But it's true that there are still places you'd expect it and not find it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Apparently not!

I was really expecting the answer to be yes for internet and could've gone either way for power sockets.

But there was no unlocked Wi-Fi signal, no signal with a name that seemed linked with the terminal or using the word "free", and no signs in the terminal with any mention of Wi-Fi as there sometimes is if the signal has a generic name.

And all of the power outlets I saw were covered too.

---

(As a bonus, the Marix Line ferry also has free Wi-Fi but so far I've only seen a very few power outlets in my 2nd class dorm. There is a charging station you can pay to use. If you do find an accessible outlet as some people did and I eventually did too, nobody was getting admonished for using them.)